# Configure SLING Logger with absolute path

Tags: logging, sling

i want to configure the sling logger with an absolute path.
Currently i have the following configuration (screenshot).

[image]

Is there any variable like ${rootdir} or somethiong else?

Thanks,
Patrick

PS: Logfile should be written to Z:\home\daycq\logs\launchpad\pacerror.log

Answer (score 0):

Windows sets absolute path with drive letter (not only forward slash).
So Z:\home\daycq\logs solves the problem.